# Action Mailer Not delivering Emails - MailCatcher and sendmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am using Rails 5. I have the following configurations in my config/environments/development.rb and config/environments/staging.rb.

config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: "localhost", port: 1025 }
```

When I call the method that sends email, I get the following output.

```
Rendering mailer/consolidated_s3_storage_report.html.erb
Rendered mailer/consolidated_s3_storage_report.html.erb (0.4ms)
Mailer#consolidated_s3_storage_report: processed outbound mail in 17668.1ms
 => #<Mail::Message:86763960, Multipart: true, Headers: <From: mcds@sheridan.com>, <To: mcds.support@sheridan.com>, <Subject: 2017 July - S3 Storage Report>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="--==_mimepart_595c962cc36fb_1be1b2198436941"; charset=UTF-8>>
```

But email is not delivered to my gmail. The 'from' address is 'default from' from which all other emails are sent. Please clarify why my emails are not delivered.

Comment: Did you check the spam folder of your gmail account... :D

Comment: Yes. It is not there too

Comment: Can you try this instead ```config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: "127.0.0.1", port: 1025 }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using Mailcatcher. Mailcatcher doesn't deliver messages, its to prevent messages from delivering to the actual `To` email addresses but lets you check of the message is framed correctly. Developers use Mailcatcher in development enviroments to see if the emails are rendered as they expect them to look like without spamming the `To` email holder.

All the emails that are sent to Mailcatcher can be viewed in a web interface. Visit [`http://localhost:1080`](http://localhost:1080) on your computer, you should be able to see all the emails you send so far from the development environment.

Comment: I was looking into http://localhost:1080 and the mailcatcher is empty. It does not have the intended emails.

Comment: If you have done `.deliver_now` on the email object and didn't see any error, it should be there in the Mailcatcher. If not, I would suggest double checking your setup.

Comment: Opps! I have not added .deliver_now while invoking the Mailer. Thanks for bringing it to notice.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the configuration for send mail to gmail:

## config/environments/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :user_name => "user@gmail.com", #your gmail id
      :password => "password", #your gmail password
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```